# javascript nested loop variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, breadcrumbs

I am writing a simple breadcrumb inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834694/721084. How I am trying to achieve this is by classifying each item by the page it would be on. The code below is meant to do that but it always ends up in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Pastebin link to entire JS code http://pastebin.com/nxUhQmqF

Sample DOM:

```
<ul id="progress_bar" class="nostyle clearfix">
    <li class="first"><a href="">Blah</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="">Blah</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="">Blah</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="">Blah</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
    function classifyPages(bcParent, totalItems) {
    var pages       = 1,
        wd          = 0,
        parentWd    = findWidthOfParent(bcParent),
        crumbs      = bcParent.find('li'),
        i           = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        wd = 0;
        while(wd < parentWd) {
            crumb = crumbs.eq(i);
            wd += crumb.outerWidth();
            if( wd < parentWd) {
                i += 1;
                crumb.addClass( 'bcPage-' + pages);
            }
        }

        pages += 1;
    }

    return pages;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us a (minimal) example DOM and how you invoke that function? Also, what does `findWidthOfParent` return?

Comment: Can you show us some html, and how you're calling this function?

Comment: are you sure crumb.outerWidth returns a valid number? If not it can go in to infinite loop.

Comment: @Bergi: updated my question with links and DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i`, which is also incremented in the inner loop, will run above `totalItems` at some time. The non-existing `crumb` then has a `outerWidth` of `0` always, and you're caught (as @Oleg V. Volkov described).

This should work:

```
function classifyPages(bcParent, totalItems) {
    var pages       = 1,
        parentWd    = findWidthOfParent(bcParent),
        crumbs      = bcParent.find('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        for (var wd = 0; wd < parentWd && i < totalItems; ) {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            var crumb = crumbs.eq(i);
            wd += crumb.outerWidth();
            if( wd < parentWd) {
                i += 1;
                crumb.addClass( 'bcPage-' + pages);
            }
        }
        pages += 1;
    }
    return pages;
}
```

Better:

```
function classifyPages(bcParent, totalItems) {
    var pages       = 1,
        parentWd    = findWidthOfParent(bcParent),
        crumbs      = bcParent.find('li'),
        wd          = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        var crumb = crumbs.eq(i);
        wd += crumb.outerWidth();
        if( wd >= parentWd) {
            pages += 1;
            wd = 0; // reset
        }
        crumb.addClass( 'bcPage-' + pages);
    }
    return pages;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this `while` loop - such constructions often happen to be source of infinite loops:

```
 while(wd < parentWd) {
            crumb = crumbs.eq(i);
            wd += crumb.outerWidth();
            // snip
```

If `crumb.outerWidth()` consistently returns 0, it will never end.